# Can someone help me figure out if I'm making a mistake in my query?

Tags: sql, sum, window-functions

I'm trying to create a query that returns the names of all people in my database that have less than half of the money of the person with the most money.
These is my query:

```
  select P1.name 
    from Persons P1 left join 
         AccountOf A1 on A1.person_id = P1.id left join 
         BankAccounts B1 on B1.id = A1.account_id
group by name
  having SUM(B1.balance) < MAX((select SUM(B1.balance) as b
                                  from AccountOf A1 left join 
                                       BankAccounts B1 on B1.id = A1.account_id
                              group by A1.person_id 
                              order by b desc 
                                 LIMIT 1)) * 0.5
```

This is the result:

```
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| Evert |
+-------+
```

I have the following tables in the database:

```
+---------+--------+--+
| Persons |        |  |
+---------+--------+--+
| id      | name   |  |
| 11      | Evert  |  |
| 12      | Xavi   |  |
| 13      | Ludwig |  |
| 14      | Ziggy  |  |
+---------+--------+--+
+--------------+---------+
| BankAccounts |         |
+--------------+---------+
| id           | balance |
| 11           | 525000  |
| 12           | 750000  |
| 13           | 1900000 |
| 14           | 1600000 |
+--------------+---------+
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| AccountOf |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| id        | person_id | account_id |
| 301       | 11        | 12         |
| 302       | 13        | 12         |
| 303       | 13        | 14         |
| 304       | 14        | 11         |
| 305       | 14        | 13         |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

What am I missing here? I should get two entries in the result (Evert, Xavi)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't approach the logic this way (I would use window functions).  But your final `having` has two levels of aggregation.  That shouldn't work.  You want:

```
having SUM(B1.balance) < (select 0.5 * SUM(B1.balance) as b
                          from AccountOf A1 join
                               BankAccounts B1 on B1.id = A1.account_id
                          group by A1.person_id
                          order by b desc 
                          limit 1
                         )
```

I also moved the `0.5` into the subquery and changed the `left join` to a `join` -- the tables need to match to get balances.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions, if your - undisclosed! - database supports them.

You can join and aggregate just once, and then use a window `max()` to get the top balance. All that is then left to is to filter in an outer query:

```
select *
fom (
    select p.id, p.name, coalesce(sum(balance), 0) balance,
        max(sum(balance)) over() max_balance 
    from persons p
    left join accountof ao on ao.person_id = p.id
    left join bankaccounts ba on ba.id = ao.account_id
    group by p.id, p.name
) t
where balance > max_balance * 0.5
```